# AWS ALB nginx-controller comination connection issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, nginx, nginx-ingress, aws-application-load-balancer

I have to build in AWS an ALB with nginx-controller to connect multiple instances in eks.

For this I have installes the loadbalancer controller. Then I have installed a node-controller with the command:

```
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
 --set-string controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local \
 --set-string controller.service.type=NodePort \
 --set controller.publishService.enabled=true \
 --set serviceAccount.create=true \
 --set rbac.create=true \
 --set-string controller.config.server-tokens=false \
 --set-string controller.config.use-proxy-protocol=false \
 --set-string controller.config.compute-full-forwarded-for=true \
 --set-string controller.config.use-forwarded-headers=true \
 --namespace kube-system
```

I selected NodePort.
Then I connect the nginx-controller with an ALB:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress 
metadata: 
  annotations: 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb  
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing 
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip 
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: 'HTTP'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: '31563' #Nodeport of the nginx-controller
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: '/healthz'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: subnet-0a0b2b0050a4a75c7,subnet-0890784d22f78fd67 #public subnets    
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP":80},{"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
  name: alb-ingress-connect-nginx 
  namespace: kube-system 
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /*
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
          backend:
            service:
              name: ssl-redirect
              port:
                name: use-annotation
        - path: /*
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
          backend:
            service:
              name: inginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller
              port:
                number: 80
```

The ALB is created well.

After this I tried to deploy a n nginx container to the domain test.mydomain.com
The container is well deployed and accessable with Lens.

After this I added a CNAME entry in Route53:

```
CNAME
test2
Data: DNS of ALB from AWS Console.
```

Hosted Zone is test.mydomain.com

But I cannot connect to the ingress in k8s. I always get 404.
Any idea where the missconfiguration happen?

Comment: Lets try something. Add `host: YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME` into the ingress config under the `spec.rules[0]` path. Beyond that you can check if your ALB listener and rules are correct